# PHP - Changing the file name destination when uploading photos

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on a web application where the user can upload photos.

I already have a PHP code where I can upload the photos to a folder in the server directory. However, the main issue I have with my code is that it keeps the original file name of the photo from before it was uploaded and after it was uploaded. My problem with that is when there are two different photos with the same file name, I'd have conflicts when they get uploaded.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


require_once '_common.php';
$config = require_once '_config.php';
$fileName = '';
$mimeType = '';
$fileSize = 0;

if (empty($_FILES)) {
    _error('No file received');
}

$pathArray = array();

foreach ($_FILES as $fileName => $fileData) {

    if (!isset($fileData['error']) ||
        is_array($fileData['error'])) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Invalid Parameters.",
            'files' => $_FILES 
        )));
    }

    switch ($fileData['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:

            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "No file sent.",
                'files' => $_FILES)));

        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Exceeded filesize limit.",
                'files' => $_FILES)));

        default:
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Unknown errors.",
                'files' => $_FILES)));
    }

    // You should also check filesize here. 
    if ($fileData['size'] > 1000000) {
            die(json_encode(array(
                'success' => false,
                'status' => "Exceeded File Size Limit.",
                'files' => $_FILES)));
    }

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($fileData['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',), 
        true)) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Invalid file format.",
            'files' => $_FILES)));
    }

    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $fileData['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('./gallery/%s',
        basename($fileData['name'])) )) {

        die(json_encode(array(
            'success' => false,
            'status' => "Failed to move uploaded file.",
            'files' => $_FILES)));
    }

    $uploaddir = '/gallery/';
    $name = $fileData["tmp_name"];

    $fullPath = sprintf('gallery/%s.%s',
        basename($fileData['tmp_name']),
        $ext

    array_push($pathArray, $fullPath);

}

print_r(json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'status' => "File is uploaded successfully.",
    'filePath' => "$fullPath"
)));
?>
```

I've lost my touch in PHP, however, this is what I've tried:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file(
    $fileData['tmp_name'],
    sprintf('gallery/%s.%s',
    sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
    $ext) 

    )) {

    die(json_encode(array(
        'success' => false,
        'status' => "Failed to move uploaded file.",
        'files' => $_FILES)));
}
```

And should that go through, I changed `$fullPath` to fit the new destination I want:

```
$fullPath = sprintf('gallery/%s.%s',
    sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
    $ext);
```

However, none of those seemed to work.

My objective is to give the uploaded files a more or less unique file name, however, I can't seem to make `sha1_file` work.

I wonder if sha1_file can be made to work, or perhaps there's another way to change the destination file name in such a way I'll end up a unique file name (using date and time for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use microtime() or uniqid() functions to concatenate with your file name:

```
if (!move_uploaded_file(
    $fileData['tmp_name'],
    sprintf('gallery/%s.%s',
    uniqid() . '_' . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
    $ext) 

    )) {

    die(json_encode(array(
        'success' => false,
        'status' => "Failed to move uploaded file.",
        'files' => $_FILES)));
}
```

See [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) documentation for more information about uniqid.

Comment: Thank you! I used `uniqid() . '_' . microtime() ` instead. and of course I changed the $fullPath variable to reflect the same as well.